# passing parameters to app on docker image

Tags: docker

I was looking around and I saw some simple examples of HelloWorld running on a docker container like this one: 
http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/docker-%E2%80%98hello-world-mono

at the end of the Dockerfile, the author calls:

```
CMD     ["mono", "/src/hello.exe"]
```

What I want to do is have a reusable image as we build our Console App.  Put that on a docker image using a Dockerfile.  That part makes sense to me.  But then I want to be able to pass the ConsoleApp  parameters.   Is that possible?

for example,

```
sudo docker run crystaltwix/helloworld -n "crystal twix"
```

where -n was a parameter I defined in my helloworld app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ENTRYPOINT foo` rather than `CMD foo` to achieve this.  All arguments after the `docker run` are passed to foo.

Comment: For some reason, this doesn't work to me as it should (Docker 1.7) without the usage of the array format like ["foo"].

Answer (score 3):

@seanmcl's answer is the simplest... if you have to pass secret values like application keys you may have to worry about exposing them is process lists.... So, you could use environment vars that you app looks for during startup:

```
SECRET_KEY="crystal twix"
docker run -e APP_KEY=$SECRET_KEY crystaltwix/helloworld
```